# Can I specify a command line recipient using bsd-mailx and Debian 8?

Tags: debian, mailx, exim

I usually configure `exim4` and `bsd-mailx` to send mail, via GMail or Google Apps, on my Debian machines.  I use a very simple `mail sent by smarthost; no local mail` Exim configuration.  I've always tested `mailx` with the following command:

```
/usr/bin/mailx -s "testing" "me@example.com" <<< "testing."
sudo exim4 -qff -v
```

However, it seems like the recipient I specify on the command line is ignored now, specifically when I use a different smarthost.  I get the following output from the above commands:

```
LOG: queue_run MAIN
  Start queue run: pid=25326 -qff
delivering 1ZHzbA-0006a6-2w (queue run pid 25326)
LOG: MAIN
  Unfrozen by forced delivery
R: smarthost for me@example
T: remote_smtp_smarthost for me@example
Connecting to [removed]:25 ... connected
  SMTP<< 220 *******************************************************************
  SMTP>> EHLO example.localnet
  SMTP<< [removed] Hello example.localnet [removed], pleased to meet you
         250-SIZE 100000000
         250-PIPELINING
         250-8BITMIME
         250 XXXA
  SMTP>> MAIL FROM:<> SIZE=2266
  SMTP>> RCPT TO:<me@example>
  SMTP>> DATA
  SMTP<< 250 Sender <> OK
  SMTP<< 550 No such domain at this location
  SMTP<< 503 Bad sequence of commands
  SMTP>> QUIT
LOG: MAIN
  ** me@example R=smarthost T=remote_smtp_smarthost: SMTP error from remote mail server after RCPT TO:<me@example>: host [removed]: 550 No such domain at this location
LOG: MAIN
  Frozen (delivery error message)
LOG: queue_run MAIN
  End queue run: pid=25326 -qff
```

Note the difference in the recipient address I attempted to specify and the `RCPT TO` address that was actually used.  As a possible hint of what's happening, the command `mailx -s "test"` will give the following error:

```
mailx: You must specify direct recipients with -t when -s, -c, or -b is used
```

However, [the manpage for bsd-mailx](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=bsd-mailx&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian%208%20jessie&format=html&locale=en) makes no mention of the `-t` switch and it doesn't indicate using the `-s` switch is going to affect the command's behavior.

I can probably figure out how to make it work with the `-t` switch, but I'm wondering if it's possible to get it working the way I'm used to.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `-t` option for `bsd-mailx`, it's [a bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=781170) regarding that error message.  You could pass recipient addresses as simple arguments to `mailx`.

I suppose you are seeing delivery failure of a bounce mail: a mail to notify sender that develivery failure occured for a mail sent previously.

Your first mail must have been sent by local exim as from `me@example` (`example` is hostname?) to `me@example.com` (you specified it with `mailx`), but it's refused by the smart host (bounced), so bounce mail from `<>` to `me@example` was newly composed and sent by local exim, then it's also refused by the smart host (double bounced).

Check the delivery log (`/var/log/mail.log`?) of your smart host and its configuration.  Is it configured to accept or relay mails to `me@example.com`?

Comment: This is exactly what my problem was.  The original message was sending before I forced the queue to process and the output I showed above was actually the (double) bounce message.  I was able to see this by using `tail -f /var/log/exim4/mainlog`.  I had done this before, but, based on your suggestion, was more observant of the message ids and was able to see I was actually dealing with two different messages.  Thanks @yaegashi.